# como puedo usar niceScroll en angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

Tengo el siguiente error al tratar de usar el *nicescroll* en angular:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).niceScroll is not a function
>           at common-scripts.js:92
>           at common-scripts.js:157
>       (anonymous) @ common-scripts.js:92
>       (anonymous) @ common-scripts.js:157
>       core.js:3073 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>       zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dcAccordion is not a function
>           at HTMLDocument. (common-scripts.js:3)
>           at c (jquery.js:4)
>           at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:4)
>           at Function.ready (jquery.js:4)
>           at HTMLDocument.q (jquery.js:4)
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>           at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>           at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (zone.js:496)
>           at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
>           at HTMLDocument.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1566)

la linea de error es :

```
$("#sidebar").niceScroll({
    styler:"fb",
    cursorcolor:"#e8403f", 
    cursorwidth: '3', 
    cursorborderradius: '10px', 
    background: '#404040', 
    spacebarenabled:false, 
    cursorborder: '', 
    scrollspeed: 60
});
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta con este codigo

```
$("#sidebar").scroll(function(){
  $("#sidebar").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

Comment: deberías agregar una explicación del mismo para que tu respuesta mejore en calidad